# Two inputboxes take 100% width of table cell

Tags: html, css, input, css-tables

I'd like my two inputboxes to take up the whole width of my table cell, with no/minimal space between the two inputboxes.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gd47b/2/

```
#one {
    width:20%;
    float: left;
}

#two {
    width:80%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p7V5X/1/)?

Comment: @RoySchoep Yes but with no/minimal space between the two inputboxes if possible.

Comment: Okay, so you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p7V5X/2/)?

Answer (score 2):

What you're is missing is that the border with 1px will take up some space so you either have to remove the border from the table or adjust the width of the text fields to accommodate.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to just split the cell the inputs are in into two cells like:

```
<table border="1" bordercolor="e2e2e2" width="400">
    <tr>
        <td><label>1</label> </td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="Name" value="Name" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td style="width:20%"><input type="text" id="one" value="one" style="width: 100%" /> </td>
        <td style="width:80%"><input type="text" id="two" value="two" style="width: 100%" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Gd47b/5/)**